# importing columns of returns data into python from excel/csv

Tags: backtesting, returns, python

I'm fairly new to the quant finance space, and I was hoping to get some guidance. Say I have a csv/excel file with columns of daily returns data for various asset classes or securities (one column per asset). I want to be able to import these returns data into Python, probably as lists/arrays.

If there are many days worth of data (say 10 years worth), what's the best way to go about this, import-wise and data structure-wise? Any packages that could help?

A minor note, I was considering using dictionaries so I could still retain the date/day, whereas if I just use lists I would just index it as 1,2,3,4...n_th day.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid this is a stack-overflow question.

Comment: I'm not sure SO would take it but it has been answered (satisfactorily IMO) now anyways. So I close it as this is not a good example of the kind of questions we want.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "I'm afraid this is a stack-overflow question" but it has already been answered.

Answer (score 1):

True this is a stackoverflow question but have you tried the fool around with the package `Pandas`? You can do in Python

`import pandas as pd`

`data = pd.read_csv('filepath/file.csv')`

That's the easiest way.